# How to insert dialog in submenu with GTK+ C++?

Tags: gtk, gtk3, gtkmm, gtk2

I'm new in GTK+ (c++).I use this version of gtk: **gtk+ bundle_3.4.2-20130513_win64** and I designed a menu (Help) with two sup menus: OpenCV and GTK.

[image]

I want to insert dialog for any of them in sub menu with GTK+ C++. Similar to this:

[image]

In fact my final result is:

[image]

But I can not. What ideas on how to solve this task would you suggest? Or on what resource on the internet can I find help?

this is my c++ code:

```
GtkWidget *vbox2 = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, FALSE);
gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(win), 10);
gtk_table_attach_defaults(GTK_TABLE(table), vbox2, 1, 2, 0, 1);

GtkWidget *menubar2 = gtk_menu_bar_new();
GtkWidget *helpMenu = gtk_menu_new();
GtkAccelGroup *accel_group2 = NULL;
accel_group2 = gtk_accel_group_new();

gtk_window_add_accel_group(GTK_WINDOW(win), accel_group2);

GtkWidget *helpMi = gtk_menu_item_new_with_mnemonic("_Help");

//opencvMi
GtkWidget *imageOpenCV, *opencvMi;
imageOpenCV = gtk_image_new_from_file("E:/Works for Gov Project/DOC    /GUI/logogui1/opencv.png");
opencvMi = gtk_image_menu_item_new_with_mnemonic("OpenCV");
gtk_image_menu_item_set_image(GTK_IMAGE_MENU_ITEM(opencvMi),     GTK_WIDGET(imageOpenCV));
gtk_widget_show(opencvMi);    

GtkWidget *linkbutton_opencv =     gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("http://www.opencv.org");

//gtkMi
GtkWidget *imageGTK,*gtkMi;
imageGTK = gtk_image_new_from_file("E:/Works for Gov Project/DOC    /GUI/logogui1/gtk.png");
gtkMi = gtk_image_menu_item_new_with_mnemonic("GTK+");
gtk_image_menu_item_set_image(GTK_IMAGE_MENU_ITEM(gtkMi),     GTK_WIDGET(imageGTK));
gtk_widget_show(gtkMi);

GtkWidget *linkbutton_gtk =     gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("http://www.gtk.org/");


GtkWidget *imprMenu2 = gtk_menu_new();

GtkWidget *imprMenu3 = gtk_menu_new();

gtk_menu_item_set_submenu(GTK_MENU_ITEM(helpMi), helpMenu);
gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(helpMenu), opencvMi);
gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(helpMenu), gtkMi);
gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(menubar2), helpMi);

gtk_menu_item_set_submenu(GTK_MENU_ITEM(opencvMi), imprMenu2);
gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(imprMenu2), linkbutton_opencv);

gtk_menu_item_set_submenu(GTK_MENU_ITEM(gtkMi), imprMenu3);
gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(imprMenu3), linkbutton_gtk);


gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox2), menubar2, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
```

and this is code for dialog (**GtkAboutDialog**):

http://zetcode.com/gui/gtk2/gtkdialogs/

Comment: Wait, I'm confused. Do you want the about dialog to literally be part of the menu, or are you trying to get it to show up as a separate window when you click the appropriate item?

Comment: @ andlabs : Thank you so much for your attention. I trying to get it to show up as a separate window when I click the appropriate item. and I want to insert gtk logo, its website,  ...... Similar to second figure.

Comment: For that you would connect to the menu item's `activate` signal to show the about dialog, not add the about dialog to the menu directly. As for showing the standard GTK+ about dialog, I'm not sure if that's possible; I don't think GTK+ provides its own About GTK+ dialog. Does OpenCV?

Comment: @ andlabs : another case? ---> dialog to literally be part of the menu??

Comment: In the screenshot you posted at http://i.stack.imgur.com/pkfsO.png, you show that you somehow got the dialog box to show up as a menu item, rather than as a dialog box. That's what I mean by literally be part of the menu. I was asking if this was what you wanted, or if you wanted the dialog box to show up when you click the GTK+ item in the menu.

Comment: @ andlabs : I said that how about another case, "dialog to literally be part of the menu "? So, Is there any method to add a dialog box to a menu item with GTK+?

Comment: @andlabs, I believe that screenshot is artificially generated. It's an example of what the OP wants.